# How to convert long millisecond in simpledate format ex "yyyy-MM-dd hh-MM-ss" in Pig Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

How to convert long millisecond in simpledate format ex:

> yyyy-MM-dd hh-MM-ss

in Pig Hadoop

```
example
input = 1409051466000
output = "yyyy-MM-dd hh-MM-ss"
```

In Pig Script.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks krishanthy-mohanachandran.

But i have good script in pig. iam trial and done.

To convert millisecond in simple dateformat `yyyy-MM-dd hh-MM-ss`

Script in pig:

```
curtime = milisecond-long (1409051466000)
```

To format I can convert it to date and then to string, in string free format.

Can add:

```
ToString(ToDate(curtime),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') as curtime
```

Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-MM-ss");
Date date = new Date(1409051466000l);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: Sory this is in pig script not java.